# Can't select from dba_tab_cols from within stored procedure (PL/SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle9i, ora-00942

I'm trying to SELECT from the dba_tab_cols view from within a stored procedure. It's not working and I don't know why.

If I execute the following SQL as a query:

```
SELECT t.data_type FROM dba_tab_cols t
WHERE 
    t.table_name = 'ACCOUNTTYPE' AND 
    t.column_name = 'ACCESSEDBY';
```

it works fine. However if I copy it into a stored procedure like so:

```
SELECT t.data_type INTO dataType FROM dba_tab_cols t
WHERE
    t.table_name = 'ACCOUNTTYPE' AND 
    t.column_name = 'ACCESSEDBY';
```

I get the error message "PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist" and the editor highlights dba_tab_cols while trying to compile. The same db user is being used in both cases.

dataType is declared as:
    dataType varchar2(128);

PL/SQL (Oracle 9)

Anybody know the issue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's most likely a priviledges issue. Is the permission to access `dba_tab_columns`  via a role or is it a direct select grant to your user? Priviledges granted via Roles aren't available in SPROCS.

A quick look on google suggests using `all_tab_cols` instead and seeing if that table has the required info you need.

Comment: Thanks that seems to work! I couldn't find the answer with Google :)

Answer (score 4):

To add to Eoin's answer:

> For most people, it comes as a
> surprise that the user cannot select
> the table from within a procedure if
> he has not been granted the select
> right directly (as opposed to through
> the role)
>
> If table user tries to compile this
> procedure, he gets a ORA-00942
> although this table certainly exists
> and he was granted the right to select
> this table. The problem is that
> procedures don't respect roles; only
> directly granted rights are respected.
> So, that means that table owner has to
> regrant the right to select:

http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/err/ora_00942.html

Answer (score -1):

I don't have oracle installed, but perhaps dataType is a reserved word. I'd try something else.